# Find / Replace a link in all pages of a site

Tags: html

Looking for ideas / recommendations on finding and replacing a link in all pages of a site, and using Dreamweaver (ick) is not an option. The site consist of 100s of static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix, vim has an option to do that.

```
vim -c "argdo %s/http:\\site.com\/pageA/http:\\site2.com\/pageB/ge | update" *.html
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/) or [Notepad++](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/)?  You can open up all your html files and then find/replace in all open documents.

Comment: It occurred to me to use Notepad++, but we're talking several pages here.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux/Unix or cygwin (or similar)

```
$ find topdir -name \*.html -print0 | 
   xargs -0 sed --in-place
   -e 's~http://foo\.com/this/that\.html~http://foo.com/other/location/newfile.html~g'
```

(line wrapped for readability)

Edit all files in-place under the directory "topdir" replacing the "/this/that.html" url with "/other/location/newfile.html" url.